# VMWare Tools Won't Install on Edubuntu (on VMware Workstation)

Tags: vmware-tools

I can install Edubuntu on workstation 11 but i cannot get VMware tools installed probably to get the display and network devices working properly.

Can anyone help or advise?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with later kernels (after 14.04) in VMware tools that they do not function correctly because of kernel changes.  This remains unpatched by VMware, but there's an open-source alternative solution that can help.

The solution is to use `open-vm-tools` from the repository which has the changes and patches to fix this.  It won't be the exact same functionality as VMware tools directly, but it will achieve generally what you need (for most VMware tools functionality).